# How to fix un alligned matrix in python

Tags: python

## Heres my code

```
    for i in range(len(new_arr)):
        new_arr[i] = new_arr[i].transpose()

     n = len(arr)
     u = [0 * n for i in range(n)]
     e = [0 * n for i in range(n)]
     print(e)
     print ("Q")
     Q = []
     for i in range(len(arr)):
     u[i] = new_arr[i] - ((np.dot(new_arr[i],e[i-1])*e[i-1]))
     e[i] = u[i] / norm(u[i])#Cari gapake norm
     e[i] = e[i].transpose()
     print(u[i])
     print(e[i])
```

But when i remove the

```
 e[i] = e[i].transpose()
```

Got an error like this :

```
shapes (1,3) and (1,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Any solutions?

Comment: instead of `[0 * n for i in range(n)]` do `[0] * n`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre doesnt change the error sir

Comment: of course not, but at least it's the correct way to do it.